# How inaccurate cpp's usleep function can be?

Tags: linux, usleep

I want to measure how inaccurate usleep can be.
I mean , if i write in my program
    usleep(5000)
what is the maximum time the sleep will be?

thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on your system's time resolution.

Comment: And I assume the system's time resolution is the amount of time in a jiffie? If so, and a jiffie is 1 millisecond on my platform, and I usleep() for 500 microseconds, does that mean I will delay for at least 1 millisecond?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a RTOS kernel, the maximum time is forever.

`usleep` (or `nanosleep` or whatever sleep) guarantees to wait for at least as long as you tell it to, rounded to the system timer granularity, *unless a signal is caught*. You know whether a signal occurred from the return value.

After that time, your thread will be ready to run, and it will run again, eventually, at the scheduler's discretion. Depending on a thousand factors that you don't know, this might be the next nanosecond or in 5 minutes, or never.

Comment: While technically correct, this is a worthless answer. 99.9% of people care about the 99.9% case, not about the theoretical limit.

Comment: @minexew: 99.9% of people never use sleep in any program _at all_ because it is almost always wrong. The OP is apparently not only one of the 0.01% who do, but also one of the 0.01% of people who do care about the worst case (hence the question!). Also, note that the lower limit ("undersleeping") is equally important and affects a lot more people than are aware of it. Hardly anyone ever checks the return value (same is true e.g. for the return value of `close`, which is similarly troublesome).

Answer (score 3):

[`usleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) on modern Linux systems uses the [`nanosleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) system call, therefore it does not suffer from the signal-related issues of older implementations. On the other hand, it's still affected by the timer resolution of your system, which is kernel and hardware specific.

That said, from the `usleep` manual page:

> POSIX.1-2001 declares this function obsolete; use nanosleep(2) instead. POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of usleep().